# Overridden style

Tags: html, css

Below is the HTML on my in built page:

```
<div class="notes quotes-notification member-savings f-left">
<h2>My Notifications</h2>
<ul>
<li><b>need to modify the HTML a little more than on the other pages you worked your account. </li>
<li>An <a href="#">answer has been posted</a> to a question you submitted.</li>
<li>A shop responded to a <a href="#">review you posted</a>.</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

`quotes-notification` and  `member-savings` both have different css as below:

```
.member-savings {
    width: 19%;
    margin-right: 1.6%; 
    border: 2px solid #0c86c9;
}
.quotes-notification{
    width: 32%; 
}
```

On the page, I need the Notification block to take width as 32%, but this block considers 19% as width and overrides the 32%. 
Here, I can not remove the class `member-savings` Is there any way to disregard 19% ?

Comment: @MyHeadHurts, Yes. problem here is I can not change the order.

Comment: Learn about CSS specificity: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: @Umesh - that is strange. The order is correct so `.quotes-notification` width should override the width of `.memeber-savings`. You could always use `!imortant` but I would try and work out why it isn't working first. Do you have a live link?

Comment: Thats pretty much the same as what i wrote in my answer! :) Specificity is a must know topic in CSS.

Comment: Your code works fine as is. http://jsfiddle.net/4T9ad/

Comment: @biziclop - nice generic response, but this is nothing to do with CSS specificity. They both have the same value and since CSS is cascading, the width should be taken from `.quotes-notification`

Comment: I suggest opening up inspector/firebug to observe what rules are actually applied and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying `!important` for `width:32%;` is one way to achieve this. But it is not a recommended practice. Another way is by trying to increase the specificity of the CSS delcaration for `quotes-notification`. i.e. instead of:

```
.quotes-notification{
    width: 32%; 
}
```

try something like:

```
body div.quotes-notification {
    width: 32%; 
}
```